# Is it possible to conditionally handle multiple different AssertionError's and Exceptions?

Tags: python-2.7, if-statement, assert, conditional-statements, bottle

Given this code block from a function in bottle-cork ([link to code](https://github.com/FedericoCeratto/bottle-cork/blob/master/cork/cork.py#L381)):

```
assert username, "Username must be provided."
assert password, "A password must be provided."
assert email_addr, "An email address must be provided."
if username in self._store.users:
    raise AAAException("User is already existing.")
if role not in self._store.roles:
    raise AAAException("Nonexistent role")
if self._store.roles[role] > max_level:
    raise AAAException("Unauthorized role")
```

I am wanting to handle the different assert 'errors' differently from an application, eg:

```
try:
    aaa.register(post_get('username'), post_get('password'), post_get('email_address'))
except AAAException as ae:
    #  do something
except AssertionError as aee:
    # do something else
```

The above works for conditional treatment of either a `AAAException` or `AssertionError` but is it possible to further refine that treatment based on the scenarios defined in the original code block ie (pseudo code):

```
try:
    aaa.register(post_get('username'), post_get('password'), post_get('email_address'))
except AAAException as ae:
    if AAAException == "User is already existing.":
            # do this
            # etc
except AssertionError as aee:
    if AssertionError == "Username must be provided.":
            # do this
            # etc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `except` block

```
except AssertionError as aee:
```

the exception object *instance* thrown is `aee`; the *class* is `AssertionError`. You need to check the content of the instance:

```
except AssertionError as aee:
    if "Username must be provided." in aee.args:
        # do your thing
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this, it worked and the explanation was great.  It's good to understand the context of the answer and that it lies in the actual class/object paradigm.